# Swift Get Next Page from header of NSHTTPURLResponse

Tags: swift, rest, api, alamofire

I am consuming an API that gives me the next page in the Header inside a field called Link. (For example Github does the same, so it isn't weird.[Github Doc](https://developer.github.com/v3/?#pagination))

The service that I am consuming retrieve me the pagination data in the following way: 
[image: pagination info]
As we can see in the "Link" gives me the next page, 
With `$0.response?.allHeaderFields["Link"]`: I get `</api/games?page=1&size=20>; rel="next",</api/games?page=25&size=20>; rel="last",</api/games?page=0&size=20>; rel="first"`.

I have found the following code to read the page, but it is very dirty... And I would like if anyone has dealt with the same problem or if there is a standard way of face with it. (I have also searched if alamofire supports any kind of feature for this but I haven't found it)

```
  // MARK: - Pagination
  private func getNextPageFromHeaders(response: NSHTTPURLResponse?) -> String? {
    if let linkHeader = response?.allHeaderFields["Link"] as? String {
      /* looks like:
      <https://api.github.com/user/20267/gists?page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/user/20267/gists?page=6>; rel="last"
      */
      // so split on "," the  on  ";"
      let components = linkHeader.characters.split {$0 == ","}.map { String($0) }
      // now we have 2 lines like '<https://api.github.com/user/20267/gists?page=2>; rel="next"'
      // So let's get the URL out of there:
      for item in components {
        // see if it's "next"
        let rangeOfNext = item.rangeOfString("rel=\"next\"", options: [])
        if rangeOfNext != nil {
          let rangeOfPaddedURL = item.rangeOfString("<(.*)>;", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
          if let range = rangeOfPaddedURL {
            let nextURL = item.substringWithRange(range)
            // strip off the < and >;
            let startIndex = nextURL.startIndex.advancedBy(1) //advance as much as you like
            let endIndex = nextURL.endIndex.advancedBy(-2)
            let urlRange = startIndex..<endIndex
            return nextURL.substringWithRange(urlRange)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return nil
  }
```

Comment: Are you looking for another solution? What's wrong with my suggestion? What you like/dislike about it? I find your question interesting, so even if I answered, I'm open to new ideas too.

Comment: @Larme Hi!, sorry for the late answer, I have had a really busy week :(, I was looking for something more flawless, something provided by swift or alamofire to treat that headers, and don't deal with the string directly, because if something changes in the future all the links will get broken, but as I see there isn't anything or at least anyone has posted it, your answer is the best and it has taken your effort and time, so I will mark is as the right one, thank you very much! :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the `forEach()` could have a better solution, but here is what I got:

```
let linkHeader = "</api/games?page=1&size=20>; rel=\"next\",</api/games?page=25&size=20>; rel=\"last\",</api/games?page=0&size=20>; rel=\"first\""

let links = linkHeader.components(separatedBy: ",")

var dictionary: [String: String] = [:]
links.forEach({
    let components = $0.components(separatedBy:"; ")
    let cleanPath = components[0].trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<>"))
    dictionary[components[1]] = cleanPath
})

if let nextPagePath = dictionary["rel=\"next\""] {
    print("nextPagePath: \(nextPagePath)")
}

//Bonus
if let lastPagePath = dictionary["rel=\"last\""] {
    print("lastPagePath: \(lastPagePath)")
}
if let firstPagePath = dictionary["rel=\"first\""] {
    print("firstPagePath: \(firstPagePath)")
}
```

Console output:

```
$> nextPagePath: /api/games?page=1&size=20
$> lastPagePath: /api/games?page=25&size=20
$> firstPagePath: /api/games?page=0&size=20
```

I used `components(separatedBy:)` instead of `split()` to avoid the `String()` conversion at the end.
I created a `Dictionary` for the values to hold and removed the `<` and `>` with a trim.

Comment: "I think that the forEach() could have a better solution,": I meant with a `reduce()` maybe, not what's inside, I think it does correctly the job, except that I didn't check if there was components.count == 2.

Comment: The forEach can be replaced with map so you can do let dictionary = links.map { ... }. (As you have said maybe with reduce too, I haven't deal with reduce and dictionaries)

Comment: There seemed to be a bug in the trimming part. I had to add a space or it wouldn't trim properly sometimes: `let cleanPath = components[0].trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: " <>"))` <<< note the extra space here. Needed to parse this: `<https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=banana&page=1>; rel=\"prev\", <https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=banana&page=3>; rel=\"next\", <https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=banana&page=34>; rel=\"last\", <https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=banana&page=1>; rel=\"first\"`